# How to call static library static class member function from victim process of dll-injection process

Tags: c++, static-libraries, dll-injection

I have successfully hooked a victim application with dll-injection.
I now need to call an un-exported singleton function of the victim process.
Is this possible, how would I go about it?

Whilst I have the object files etc of the victim process I am unable to rebuild/deploy new versions, so I can't just create a function with export linkage.

I have tried code in my hook process:

```
#include "VictimSingleton.h"
//...
void SomeFuncInHook()
{
  VictimSingleton *vs = VictimSingleton::Get();
  vs->DoThing();
}
```

internally Get() is implemented like:

```
VictimSingleton* VictimSingleton::Get()
{
  static VictimSingleton singleton;
  return &singleton;
}
```

**Expected Result:** VictimSingleton::Get() returns same address when called from my hook or my victim process.

**Actual result:** The pointer returned by Get, whilst valid, refers to a different VictimSingleton than the one used by the victim process.

I guess that is because it is two separate translation units, so it creates a different version of the singleton when called from my hook process.

Comment: *Why* do you want/need to do this?

Comment: Get the base address of Kernel32.dll.. then calculate the offset from the base address to your function `SomeFuncInHook`.. In the remote process, add the offset to Kernel32's base address and now you have a function pointer.. You can invoke it with CreateRemoteThread.. and so on.. It should call the one in the remote process.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am wanting to access a function of a released application I have previously released from my working dll-injected hook. Unfortunately because this particular function is in a static lib and not declared declspec(DLL_EXPORT) I can't simply GetProcAddress for the function I want to call. AFAIK?

Comment: @Brandon thanks for that I'll give that a go.

Comment: Is the trouble that you don't know how to call a member function in a hook using an object that already exists as the this pointer?

Comment: @GuidedHacking I don't think so. I have a release app.exe so can't re-compile/re-release, I wanted to call a static function defined in that app.exe from my hook.dll. All this was with the intention of being able to use functionality within the app.exe from the hook.dll, in the end time got the best of me on this and I ended up re-implementing the functionality I needed within the hook itself. Hopefully I'll get another chance to look into this as Brandon's suggestion sounded a good bet.

Comment: If you just need to call a function, that's easy, what is the calling convention of this funtion?  Is it a member function? thiscall, stdcall, cdecl, etc?  If you still need help let me know I can help I just need more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function is not exported, you don't have a PDB and debug symbols aren't embedded then first you must find the function, using a disassembler such as IDA Pro.  If it is a virtual function then finding it will be much easier because you can expose the Run Time Type Information with an IDA plugin such as Class Informer, this will give you a list of all the vtable functions.

Once you have the address of the function you need to reverse it's calling convention and it's arguments.  Most likely this is a __thiscall function because it's a member function.

Next, in order to call a member function you require a class instance to pass as the this pointer.  To do so, you can also find the class's constructor and call that, using it's return as your instance.

Next, you need to call the function.  To call a __thiscall function you actually call it as a __fastcall and you pass the address of the object you created as the this pointer as the first argument, and a 0 for the second variables, following by the actual function arguments.

The second argument is a zero because __fastcall expects a variable passed in EDX.

Typedef a function pointer prototype, create an instance of this function pointer, assign it the address of the function and then call it.

```
typedef void(__fastcall* fFunc)(void* thisptr, void* not_edx, float arg1, int arg2);

fFunc Func = (fFunc)0xDEADC0DE; //address of function

Func(objectPtr, 0, 1.0f, 2);
```