# DLL fails to inject when using static library

Tags: c++, dll, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I'm trying to make a DLL that can be injected into processes that uses external libraries (`MinHook`, `socket.io-client-cpp`) yet whenever I attempt to use anything from `sioclient` the DLL fails to inject.

`sioclient.lib` is in the linker's additional dependencies and additional library directories, and it compiles fine.

Including `sio_client.h` works fine and has no effect, but adding `sio::client h;` to the code causes the DLL to not inject at all and fail on injection. I've tried multiple injectors and injection methods with the same result.

The thing that confuses me the most is that I can use functions from MinHook like `MH_Initialize` just fine, the DLL injects and the functions run fine, and I'm linking `libMinHook.lib` in the exact same way as `sioclient.lib`, so why can't I use anything from `sioclient`?

I also tried this with `IXWebSocket`, with the exact same result as `sioclient`, for some reason `MinHook` is the only library that works.

Any help is appreciated, I've been at this trying different things for hours.

Comment: This is a surprising statement: _DLL fails to inject when using static library_. DLLs are using global trampoline tables with function pointers (and variables) where you have a point to intercept. The same is true if you provide a replacement DLL with equally named functions. This is what makes DLL injection possible. However, static libraries are linked statically at compile-time. (That's why they are called "static libraries".) There is no trampoline table and no resolution of function pointers at run-time. So, how should injection work in this case?

Comment: Maybe, this is something similar: [SO: How to call static library static class member function from victim process of dll-injection process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61293561/7478597) (I must admit I didn't think of disassembling and hard-coding addresses. I wouldn't use this in productive code, maybe, because my work is targeted to industrial customers but not game hackers...) ;-)

Comment: Basically I'm making a native node module to allow for hooking process functions, I tried "external hooking" for a bit but couldn't get anything working, so I'm now opting to make a DLL that communicates with my module and does all the hooking. I spent a while going over different IPC methods and decided to use webhooks, but all the webhook libraries I can find have this issue where the DLL always fails to inject if anything from the libs is used.